# Redirect Curl Calls From Specific IP On Localhost

Tags: iptables, curl, iptables-redirect

I've a node server that serves `localhost:90`, and we need to direct all curl calls from WITHIN the machine on `168.92.168.92` to `localhost:90`.

How can this be achieved? Would this be using iptables?

I tried OUTPUT and PREROUTING but the request fails to connect.

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3339 packets, 200K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  168.92.168.92 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 to:127.0.0.1:90 

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3339 packets, 200K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 6220 packets, 652K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8         ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL 
2        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       168.92.168.92          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 to:127.0.0.1:90
```

Output:

```
# curl -v http://168.92.168.92/hello
* About to connect() to 168.92.168.92 80 (#0)
*   Trying 168.92.168.92... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
Curl directly to the server on localhost:90 works, but curl on 168.92.168.92 does not.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it possible that some use of iptables' masquerade feature is needed? I know practically nil about iptables but was curious and poked around a bit, finding a number of references to redirecting/rerouting involving use of this feature. For example, see [How-To: Redirecting network traffic to a new IP using IPtables](https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-to-a-new-ip-using-iptables/).